# How to remove punctuation marks from a list of strings without using libraries in Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to remove all punctuation marks (without being specific) and '\n' from a list of strings as for example:

```
l = ['``What ails you, Sister Erin, that your face\n', 'Is, like your mountains, still bedewed with tears?\n', 'As though some ancient sorrow or disgrace,\n']
```

output:

```
['What ails you Sister Erin that your face', 'Is like your mountains still bedewed with tears', 'As though some ancient sorrow or disgrace']
```

I'm trying to do it without using libraries.

Comment: `[''.join(a for a in s if a.isalpha() or a == ' ') for s in l]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use any external libraries for this. The basic `str` type can deal with this.

See below:

```
l = ['``What ails you, Sister Erin, that your face\n', 'Is, like your mountains, still bedewed with tears?\n',
     'As though some ancient sorrow or disgrace,\n']

l = ["".join([char for char in line if char.isalnum() or char == " "]) for line in l]
print(l)
```

You just need to ignore all characters which are not alphanumeric or space

Answer (score 0):

Try this Solution:

```
unwanted_char = [#put the punctuation marks that you want to remove here ]
for char in unwanted_char:
    data = data.replace(char, "")
```